# Is it correct $E(u^a)=0?$ and $E(\log u )=0$? For u~N(0,$\sigma^2$)

Tags: regression, expected-value, standard-error, error

Let u be error and u~N(0,$\sigma^2$)

Then what is this $E(\log u )=$?

Is this equal to zero?

And$E(u^a)=0$? Where a is scalar.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $u$ can take negative values, $\log u$ is not defined for negative $u$, hence $E[\log u]$ is also not defined (strictly speaking, undefined in the field of real numbers; you could extend the definition to complex logarithms, but not sure it would be useful for your case).

Regarding $E[u^a]$, it is zero if $a$ is an odd integer, since the normal distribution is symmetric, $u$ is centered around zero and we know these moments exist for the normal (in general you need to check if it is well defined). It's not zero for non-odd integer, for instance, $E[u^2] = \sigma^2$.

Comment: $\log u$ is defined for negative $u$; say rather that the answer doesn't help here.

Comment: @NickCox you mean briefly mentioning complex logarithms?

Comment: Quite so; here any desire for rigour ousts clarity and need-to-know.